# Lazy loading plugin and Jscroll not working together and images are not loading

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

i have use a jscroll plugin and also used a lazy loading plugin in my application.
now on scroll my content is load and replace properly but my images are not load.

see my code:--

```
$('#product-grid').jscroll({
        debug: true,
        autoTriggerUntil: 2,
        nextSelector: '.pager a:last',
        contentSelector: '.product-grid',
        callback:call()
    });

function call()
    {
        alert("hi");
        $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    }
```

now in above code see i used a callback function but it's not call after all scroll. why?
can any one help me ?

i have another issue too. i have set autoTriggerUntil: 2, but after 2 trigger there is no any next link so how can i solve this.?

please reply

i need help

regards,
vinit

Comment: please any one can give me suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove () from your jscroll function.

for ex:-

```
callback: call,
```

and try to remove that lazyloading from this callback function call.

it should be work.